# How do the changes in the Black Company campaign setting affect game balance (D&D 3.5)?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, black-company-setting

The Black Company campaign setting for D&D 3.5 (Green Ronin publishing, based on the Glen Cook novels) made significant changes to game mechanics. For example:

- Spellcasting was completely revamped to use casting checks and an elaborate system for spell customization (similar to 3e epic spells from the Epic Level Handbook)
- Many of the core classes were rewritten to focus on their martial/nonmagical aspects. For example, the ranger class was made non-magical, and a scout class was added, sitting somewhere in between the ranger and rogue.
- As a core rule, characters had a "massive damage" threshold that could cause one big hit to drop them, even if they had a lot of hit points.

A question to anybody who has played this campaign setting: **did the core system changes introduced in this setting work well from a balance perspective?** Specifically:

- Were the modified martial classes (e.g. fighter, thief, scout, ranger, etc) relatively well-balanced against each other?
- Were martials well-balanced against wizards?
- Did the game hold together at higher levels?

Comment: I'm still not confident about the scope of this question. It would be stackable if it were about homebrew balance though, so it should be okay to ask the same question about a published product.

Comment: This still lacks focusses: what would the revamp do? What's the rewrite going to do to the classes?

Comment: @Trish Those questions are answered by the published sourcebook that this question is asking about? This is not a proposal or anything, it’s an existing product that Harris wants to get the measure of. I’m not familiar with it myself but for someone who is, this seems like a perfectly answerable and reasonable question.